# Which on-line resources to use for an Austrian definition of a term?

Tags: meaning, online-resource, osterreich

Looking for an Austrian definition of the term "Multikulturalismus." Or do Austrians simply use a German dictionary such as "Duden"?

Answer (score 2):

Note this is not an Austria-specific term, but a neologism built from "multikulturell" undergone a standard German nominalisation for loanwords.

The [online edition of the official Austrian dictionary](https://www.oewb.at/oebv/oewb/start.xav) does, however, not know it. (And the German Duden doesn't as well, which is quite common for standard nominalisations)

With regards to your title question, you might want to consult this Wikipedia article: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Wörterbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch)

Both the Duden and the ÖWB know, however, the original adjective *multikulturell* with basically identical definitions.